# Upload image on 'My Account' page frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I would like to have my customers upload an image on their account page. I can add an image attribute to my customer model by using the following code. Any idea on how to put this on the frontend and make it work?

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'logo', array(
            'type'     => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'label'    => 'Logo',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
            'input'    => 'image',
            'visible'  => true,
            'required' => false,
            'default' => '0',
            'frontend' => '',
            'unique'     => false,
            'note'       => '',
            'system'    => false,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ));

$logo = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "logo");

    $logo = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'logo');
    $used_in_forms2[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms2[]="customer_account_edit";
    $logo->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms2)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 101);

    $logo->save();
```

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can you use my extension - "Profile Avatar", look up on marketplace.

Extension provide:

- Customer dashboard section with upload tools
- Show profile images in user list on product page

and you will can use my block views for your projects

marketplace direct link on these extension: http://marketplace.magento.com/sy-avatar.html